# how to print request body in urllib3 python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib3

I can successfully make a post multipart request using **urllib3 library in python**. However how to print the request body when POST request was made?

In ***python requests library***: we have the option like: **print(response.request.body)**

code looks like this:

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

```
path_bdl = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/some_bin_file.xyz'
content_json = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/some_json.json'


with open(path_, 'rb') as fp:
    binary_data = fp.read()

with open(content_json, 'r') as j:
    json_data1 = j.read()

url = "//myurl"

headers = {}  # dictionary

response = http.request(
    'POST',
    url,
    fields={
        "abc": (content_json, json_data1, "application/json"),
        "bbb": (path_, binary_data, "xyz_Content_type")
    },
    headers=headers
)

print('\n StatusCode: ', response.status)
print(response.headers)
print(response.request) >>>>>>>>>>>> HTTPResponse has no attribute 'request'
```

Answer (score -2):

From the [docs](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#response-content):

> The HTTPResponse object provides status, data, and headers attributes

Try using `response.data` for reading the data part of the response.